# deferred.always() fires too early

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var xhr1 = $.ajax({ url:'/echo/json/', data:{ delay: 3 } }),
    xhr2 = $.ajax({ url:'/echo/json/something/invalid', data:{ delay: 3 } });

xhr1.always(function(){
    console.log('xhr1 always');
});

xhr2.always(function(){
    console.log('xhr2 always');
});

$.when.apply($, [xhr1, xhr2]).always(function(){
    console.log('xhr1 & xhr2 always');
});
```

Result (console):

```
xhr2 always
xhr1 & xhr2 always
xhr1 always
```

Why doesn't `deferred.always()` wait for both ajax calls to be completed? Is there any defered callback which can be used when all requests are done, regardless of their status?

http://jsfiddle.net/W9A3f/

Comment: You're already using `.when()`, just add `.then()` to that and you should have the means to wait for all the responses.

Comment: @DevlshOne I believe that `then()` only is called if both calls are successful.

Comment: That's correct. Are you saying that the OP wants a result even if a call fails?

Comment: @DevlshOne yes, that's what he wants

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.when(...)` will trigger its callbacks when *all* of them are `resolved`, or as soon as *any* of them are `rejected`.

Since the second AJAX call results in an error, the `.when().always()` happens as soon as the second AJAX call error happens, whether or not the first AJAX call succeeded yet or not.

The only solution I know of for your scenario is to keep a second `$.Deferred` around for each AJAX request, and then `resolve` those in each AJAX request's `always` handler.  Then use *those* deferreds in your `$.when` call:

```
var def1 = $.Deferred();
xhr1.always(def1.resolve);

var def2 = $.Deferred();
xhr2.always(def2.resolve);

$.when(def1, def2).done(function() {
    // only called when the two XHRs complete, whether
    // they succeeded or not
});
```

Comment: So, is there any way to make a synchronized callback?